# How to center Items in react

Tags: css, reactjs

Im crating a navbar for a cite and currently formatting the page Im pretty new to react so im trying to start with the basics. I am stuck on how to center my NavBarLinks, I have used text-center and position to make the links be in the center of the navbar but if I make the web browser smaller it wont stay in the center. My question is what is the right to center items in react.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  NavbarContainer,
  TopContainer,
  BottomContainer,
  NavbarExtendedContainer,
  NavbarInnerContainer,
  NavbarLinkContainer,
  NavbarLink,
  Logo,
  OpenLinksButton,
  NavbarLinkExtended,
} from "../styles/Navbar.style";
import LogoImg from "../assets/logo.png";

function Navbar() {
  const [extendNavbar, setExtendNavbar] = useState(false);

  return (
    <NavbarContainer extendNavbar={extendNavbar}>
      <NavbarInnerContainer>
        <TopContainer>
          <NavbarLinkContainer>
            <OpenLinksButton
              onClick={() => {
                setExtendNavbar((curr) => !curr);
              }}
            >
              {extendNavbar ? <>&#10005;</> : <> &#8801;</>}
            </OpenLinksButton>
            <Logo src={LogoImg}></Logo>
          </NavbarLinkContainer>
        </TopContainer>
        <BottomContainer>
        <NavbarLinkContainer>
        <NavbarLink to="/"> Home</NavbarLink>
            <NavbarLink to="/products"> Products</NavbarLink>
            <NavbarLink to="/contact"> Contact Us</NavbarLink>
            <NavbarLink to="/about"> About Us</NavbarLink>
        </NavbarLinkContainer>
        </BottomContainer>
      </NavbarInnerContainer>
      {extendNavbar && (
        <NavbarExtendedContainer>
          <NavbarLinkExtended to="/"> Home</NavbarLinkExtended>
          <NavbarLinkExtended to="/products"> Products</NavbarLinkExtended>
          <NavbarLinkExtended to="/contact"> Contact Us</NavbarLinkExtended>
          <NavbarLinkExtended to="/about"> About Us</NavbarLinkExtended>
        </NavbarExtendedContainer>
      )}
    </NavbarContainer>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Style page

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const NavbarContainer = styled.nav`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  @media (min-width: 700px) {
    height: 80px;
  }
`;

export const TopContainer = styled.div`
  padding-left: 5%;
`;

export const BottomContainer = styled.div`
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color:salmon;
`;

export const NavbarInnerContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
`;

export const NavbarLinkContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

export const NavbarLink = styled(Link)`
  color: white;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: 43%;
  top:10%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavbarLinkExtended = styled(Link)`
  color: white;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
`;

export const Logo = styled.img`
  @media (min-width: 700px) {
    margin: auto;
  }
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 180px;
  height: auto;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend using a whole different page for `css` instead just add your code to `index.css`, from there you can access your `css` from any `component` in your `react` app.

And to center the `NavbarLink` you can use `flexbox`.

Create some `css` code in `index.css`:

```
.navbar__link {
  width: 100%
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And add that `class` in your `component element`:

```
<NavbarLinkContainer className='navbar__link'>
  <NavbarLink to="/"> Home</NavbarLink>
  <NavbarLink to="/products"> Products</NavbarLink>
  <NavbarLink to="/contact"> Contact Us</NavbarLink>
  <NavbarLink to="/about"> About Us</NavbarLink>
</NavbarLinkContainer>
```